# How to not crop the background when resizing the browser to smaller size?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

You have for example: stackoverflow.com when you resize the width of your browser to smaller size you will see a large padding from the right, same for this webpage http://www.hyper.no/ (bottom page footer)

I'm not sure if they are using Compass blueprint, but I am and I have this problem when adding  the @include container it adds the following css:
    width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    *zoom: 1;

I would like that the width get 100% even resizing the browser to smaller size

Comment: Please clarify. You want a div to take up 100% of the available width no matter how wide or thin the window is?

Comment: exactly, when you look at the footer of stackoverflow, it doesn<t take up to 100% of the browser, WHEN you resize the browser to a smaller size than the body width. There is a large white padding added on the right of the browser

Comment: That's caused by the programmer not correctly coding the CSS. Please provide *your* code, so that I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer for this, it's quite simple for example you put a width of 960px and when you resize your windows to a smaller size, just put min-width:960px on your body and you won't see the gap. I spent 3 hours to find it...